# How to add resourse folder to the expansion file

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am new in this question. So my app have drawable folder with many images (more than 100mb). If I try to create and upload this app, playmarket will not allow me to do this. I want to add images to the expansion file (to reduce app size). As I understood I have to pack these images into .zip file and name it like main.1.my.package.name.zip
Then I have to upload app without images to playmarket and then upload these images inside .zip file. But how can I separate drawable images from my app?? I have many references (like R.drawable.image) inside an app. Android Studio simply will not allow me to build apk without these images. 
May be I don't understand the simplest things.. Please tell me where I'm incorrect. It would be great if someone share his experience of creating expansion files.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a new folder at the same level as your "main" directory and name it as you please. In this new folder you will need to copy the structure and use the same name for the drawables you want to override.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy the structure"?